# How to search data by just date only

Tags: php, mysql

I have data in mysql table in datetime form but when i want to search in php screen i just want data to show with respect to date.For now my sql query is.

```
$datefrom=date($_GET['datefrom']);

$dateto=date($_GET['dateto']);

$issues = $database->select("tablename", "*", [
    "dateadded[<>]" => [$datefrom,  $dateto]
]);
```

What will be the solution.Please guide

Comment: I don't think you get what you want with `date($_GET['datefrom'])`.. You need `strtotime()`, or better yet - use the DateTime or Carbon class.

Comment: Which framework are you using? What is the date format of your column field and what is the date format of your requested data?

Comment: not using any framework.This 2019-02-05 13:41:47 is date format in column and this 2019-04-08 date format which i requested.

Comment: If you're not using a framework, show your class where `$datetime` is defined from. That method is not standard.

Comment: You can possibly just remove the `date()` around your date-definitions then. `date()` is used to format dates, you are currently not using it right.

Comment: //function
function dateDb2($date) {
    $format = explode(";",getConfigValue("date_format"));

    if($date != "")  {
        $dateObj = date_create_from_format($format[0],$date);
        return date_format($dateObj,"Y-m-d");
    }

    else return "";
}

//requested data
$datefrom=dateDb2($_GET['datefrom']);

$dateto=dateDb2($_GET['dateto']);

Answer (score 1):

Try with this -

```
$datefrom = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($_GET['datefrom']) );

$dateto   = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($_GET['dateto']) );

$issues   = $database->select("tablename", "*", [
    "dateadded[<>]" => [$datefrom,  $dateto]
]);
```

**OR**

Try this if both to & from date is different -

```
 $d1 = $_GET['datefrom'].' 00:00:00';
 $d2 = $_GET['dateto'].' 00:00:00';

 $datefrom = date($d1);

 $dateto   = date($d2);

SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `datecol` BETWEEN '2018-11-27 00:00:00' and '2018-12-07 00:00:00'
```

**AND**

For same day search use this kind of query -

```
SELECT * FROM datetable WHERE datecol LIKE '2012-12-25%'
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It is showing dateto and datefrom in this 2019-08-04 12:00:00 format ,i will get null data with this because no data is present in table with this time slot ,is it possilbe it will just search data by just date ignore time slot from table.Like i have data with this " 2019-04-08 10:40:02 "but when i search data with just date its not showing data.I want to search data just with respect to date .I hope my question is clear

Comment: You can do one more thing as, $d1 = $_GET['datefrom'].' 00:00:00';  date($d1); This will return date in 2019-08-04 00:00:00 format like wise add '23:59:59' time in dateto variable. e.g: SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE columname BETWEEN '2019-08-04 00:00:00' AND '2019-08-04 23:59:59'